# Autoconf on Windows 7 dreadfully slow

Tags: performance, windows-7, mingw, autotools, autoconf

I am working on a project using Google's cmockery unit testing framework. For a while, I was able to build the cmockery project with no problems. e.g. "./configure", "make && make install" etc. and it took a reasonable amount of time (1-2 minutes or so.) After working on other miscellaneous tasks on the computer and going back to re-build it, it becomes horrendously slow. (e.g. after fifteen minutes it is still checking system variables.)

I did a system restore to earlier in the day and it goes back to working properly for a time. I have been very careful about monitoring any changes I make to the system, and have not been able to find any direct correlation between something I am changing and the problem. However, the problem inevitably recurs (usually as soon as I assume I must have accidentally avoided the problem and move on). The only way I am able to fix it is to do a system restore to a time when it was working. (Sometimes restarting the machine works as well, sometimes it does not.)

I imagine that the problem is between the environment and autoconf itself rather than something specific in cmockery's configuration. Any ideas?

I am using MinGW and under Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that antivirus software is not interfering. Often, antivirus programs monitor every file access; autoconf accesses many files during its operation and is likely to be slowed down drastically.

Comment: I was using Comodo Internet Security; after uninstalling it, my problem seems to be solved.